# Why tableau is not removing Users from All users when I remove AD group?

Tags: tableau-api

We just purchase tableau 10 and we are new to Tableau. I am having a following problem.

I am adding AD group to the site I created, it adds all user that are in AD group but when I want to remove AD group, AD group gets removed but all users are still listed under All Users. I am syncing Tableau with AD directory every 15 minutes and still they are listed there and all users in AD group are still able to signing in into Tableau Site. Any suggestion what I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, deleting a group wont delete the users. To delete users you need to go to the users tab and select the users you want to delete.

See more : http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/deleting-user-from-tableau-server